# Stardardization for Random Forest, SVM and Logistic Regression

Tags: classification, random-forest, svm, standardization, data-preprocessing

I have a classification project and I want to compare three models: Random Forest, SVM and Logistic Regression.
Random Forest are tree based algorithms wheras, SVM is a distance based model and LR is probabilistic model.
The dataset for SVM and LR needs to be standardized but it doesn't have to be for RF.
So my question is about what is the best approach to compare the models' performances:

- Standardize the dataset for all three models and thus the reuslts can be copmpared because it is the same dataset.
- Standardize the dataset for LR and SVM but not RF, but this way the 3 models aren't trained on the same dasetset.
  Thank you.